# Retrieve column title from excel file using linux grep command or any command

Tags: linux, excel, grep

```
    SNO     Name      Phone         email  
    1       ABC     1234567890   abc@gmail.com
    2       DEF     9874563210   def@gmail.com
```

Check the table that i have specified above. I have a set of records. I need to retrieve the column titles alone.

i.e : SNO, Name, Phone and email.

Any Linux command is fine. preferably GREP command. I tried grep and I am able to retrieve full record

Example:

```
2    DEF    9874563210  def@gmail.com
```

But i want only the column title. How do i extract it. Please help

Comment: Are you talking about a real MS Excel file (.xls or .xlsx)? Or just a tab-separated values (TSV) file? If the former, a simple grep command isn't likely to help, unless you use Excel or a compatible program to export to TSV.

Comment: just show the first line? as mentioned by @devnull

Comment: yes just the first line.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can save your excel as csv, but you will have to know the name of your last column to display the first line.
So you will have this csv file:

```
SNO     ,Name      ,Phone         ,email  
1,ABC     ,1234567890,abc@gmail.com
2,DEF     ,9874563210,def@gmail.com
```

and then just type this command.

```
C:\Users\admin\Desktop>grep -B 1 -i "email" ex.csv
```

the result will be

```
SNO     ,Name      ,Phone         ,email
```

Comment: But what if i do not know the last column's name? I actually dont know the last column name. In this case hoe do i retrieve?

Comment: You know at least one of columns name? if you do, you can use one of this:
`grep -A 0 -i "column's name" ex.csv` or 
    `grep -B 0 -i "column's name" ex.csv` or 
    `grep -C 0 -i "column's name" ex.csv`

`